# JSON file contains unwanted space and newline characters

Tags: php, json

I tried to parse a big JSON file using PHP and it always give me errors.
When I tried to validate the JSON file using http://jsonlint.com/ I encountered a lot of error in which there are some words separated by "unwanted" space and newline character like this:

```
{
                "id": "1",
                "qn
 ame": "detik.co.id.",
                "source": "undefined"
},
```

notice the word "qname" is separated into "qn" and "ame". between those two there are space and newline characters.

the correct one should look like this:

```
{
                    "id": "1",
                    "qname": "detik.co.id.",
                    "source": "undefined"
 },
```

since there are a lot of similar error it would be painful to remove those characters manually one by one. Is there any quicker way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Where are you getting such crap JSON from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the data, you could just get rid of *all* the space and newline characters:

```
tr -d ' \n' < input_json.txt > spaceless_json.txt
```

But of course that will break if you have data with embedded spaces like:

```
"var one" : 1
```

Comment: [Yes, it is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29).  You could get Cygwin or some other Windows implementation of `tr`, or probably do the same thing in almost any text-editing program.

Answer (score 0):

Try str_replace(), if the command line option doesn't work:

```
$parsed = json_decode( str_replace( array( "\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t" ), '', $nasty_string_from_file ) );
```